# How to host your WordPress theme on github and make my theme updatable for my client

Tags: github

I'm currently developing an WordPress theme for a client of mine. I want it to be hosted on GitHub, so my client can update the theme whenever I release a new update of the theme.
The problem is that I don't know how to host a theme on GitHub and have a private key saved in the code somewhere, without anyone can see it.

Can someone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you already see [this Q&A from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71847398/update-wordpress-theme-plugin-from-private-github-repo)?

Comment: Yeah, I have already seen that, but I'm still confused how to set it up. @kero

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WP Pushar](https://wppusher.com/) to update the theme from github. It will give you synchronize button in the dashboard to synchronize it with github repo.

Here is overview video you can use WP Pusher with your site.

Here is article that explaining how you can update theme from github using WP Pusher. Also watch that video to understand it more clearly. [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IH4Xv8wJ60k)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But is there another way to do it? 
I don't want my clients to download a plugin to update my theme, so yeah.

Comment: Hi @Mushy. If you don't want to use any extra plugin then I think it will be best to use GitHub Actions. Please go through that article to understand what is GitHub Actions and how you can use it with WordPress.

Comment: That's the other way around, though? That would be pushing the theme update to the site rather than the site pulling the update from GitHub. Which would work too, provided you've got filesystem access credentials for your customers that you're willing to store as secrets in GitHub